# How to access images using tensorflow dataset

Tags: python, tensorflow, dataset, tensorflow-datasets

Recently I downloaded CelebA data set from [this page](https://mmlab.ie.cuhk.edu.hk/projects/CelebA.html). Now I want to access it using `tfds.load` function from `tensforflow_dataset` package.

My zip file named `celeb_a` is placed in folder `C:/Users/name`

To access it from python I used code:

```
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds

ds = tfds.load("celeb_a", data_dir=r'C:\Users\name', split='train', download=False)
```

Resulting in error:

```
AssertionError: Dataset celeb_a: could not find data in C:\Users\name. Please make sure to call dataset_builder.download_and_prepare(), or pass download=True to tfds.load() before trying to access the tf.data.Dataset object.
```

I also tried to use:

```
builder = tfds.image.CelebA(data_dir="C:/Users/name")
```

before calling `tfds.load` however output is exactly the same.

Downloading CelebA dataset using python is very complex due to very easy exceed of daily quota - thats the reason why I downloaded it from official page and now I want to manually load it to python. Could you please help me doing so?

Comment: `data_dir` expects the data to be already unzipped (and prepared accordingly to what `download_and_prepare` does in the dataset's definition). You'll have to redo the prepare steps yourselves on the zip file and place the result of that in C:/Users/name, for tfds.load to work.

Comment: I extracted zip file, so now I have a folder containing CelebA dataset named `celeb_a`. I used code `builder.download_and_prepare(download_dir=r"C:/Users/name")` and I got error:  `Failed to create a directory: C/Users/name/celeb_a\celeb_a\0.3.0.incompleteOFHXNF; No such file or directory`. Do you know why?

Comment: Ohh..I think I understand. So `download_and_prepare` downloads a dataset and prepare it. However, because I'm not downloading it I have to "prepare" it by myself. Is that correct?

Comment: Indeed. I'm checking if there is a way to tell TFDS "please use this archive instead of redownloading everything", but I couldn't find anything yet

Comment: Also, a side note about _"Downloading CelebA dataset using python is very complex due to very easy exceed of daily quota"_: You only download (and prepare) the dataset once, the next times you use it it will reuse the already prepared data, so quotas shouldn't really  be an issue.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your statement that quotas shouldn't be in issue. I try to download `CelebA` dataset using `tensorflow` or `torchvision`, but I can't because daily quota is exceeded. I know that only have to do it once, but I can't do it even once.